# django: how to see that email and username are always stored in lowercase or unique even if not lowercase

Tags: python, django

I want to store username and email for each user and want them to be unique

I have two options:

1. save both the username and email in lowercase so that their uniqueness is checked by the model by default
2. store them whatever way the user provides (can be mix of lower and upper case). Then how to ensure they are distinct.

Also when i user the `authenticate()` to authenticate the username and password. How to ensure that it checks irrespective lower or upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on the language of the content. If it's only English, then you can use [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) lookup for case insensitive query look-up.

To use authenticate, you will need to validate that the user exists first (what I mentioned above), and pass this user's username to `authenticate` function.